# Exact RG as field redefinition

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, path-integral, effective-field-theory

In Rosten's review of exact RG ([arXiv:1003.1366](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1366)), exact RG can be recast as field redefinition, but I don't see why it should be general discussion. Could you possibly explain to me why exact RG should be expressed as field redefinition?

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, Ref. 1 only claims that changes to *redundant/inessential$^1$* coupling constants can be absorbed into quasi-local field redefinitions [by the very definition of the notion].

References:

1. O.J. Rosten, *Fundamentals of the Exact RG,* [arXiv:1003.1366](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1366); eqs. (3.20) + (3.47) + (5.8).

---

$^1$ NB: *Redundant/inessential* is not necessarily the same as *irrelevant.*